# How to "see" php variable in multiple <?php ?>

Tags: php, html, forms

Ok i will show you code, you should understand from it what i want, problem is it doesnt recognize variable from one php tags inside other php tags on same page which is contact.php...

```
<form action="contact.php" method="POST">
        <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name"><?php $nameErr=' '; echo $nameErr; ?></p>
        <p>Email: <input type="email" name="email"><?php $emailErr=' '; echo $emailErr; ?></p>
        <p>Message:</p> <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea><br />
        <p><?php $messageErr= ' '; echo $messageErr; ?></p>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit1">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email= $_POST['email'];
        $message= $_POST['message'];
        $formcontent= "From: $name \n Message: $message";
        $recipient= "konstantin91@gmail.com";
        $subject= "Contact Form";
        $mailheader= "From: $email \r\n";
        if(strlen($name)==0) {
            $nameErr = "Name is required <br>";
            die();
        }
        elseif(strlen($email)==0) {
            $emailErr = "Email is required";
            die();
        }
        elseif(strlen($message)==0) {
            $messageErr "Message is required <br>";
            die();
        }
        else {

            echo "$name, thank you for submiting message";
        }
    }
?>
```

I made all $varErr variables empty strings by default so when you first enter contact.php you see nothing, but when you submit form IF checks if field is empty, if it is empty i want inline with form field to echo $varErr for that field ($nameErr or $emailErr, $messageErr will go under textarea field cause i want it like that)

Hope you understand what i want, i have finished everything just that form and i am done.. Ofcourse i can avoid all of this by echoing under form error for empty form fields but that is not what i want...

Comment: PSS : You are missing `=` near your `$messageErr "Message is required <br>";`

Answer (score 0):

In your original code `$nameErr`, `$emailErr` and `$messageErr` are changed after showing them.

If you make something like:

```
<?php $something = "value1";
echo $something;
$something = "value2";
?>
```

it will show `value1` on the screen.

It should be something like this:

```
    <?php
        $nameErr='';
        $emailErr=''; 
        $messageErr= ''; 
        if ($_POST) {

            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email= $_POST['email'];
            $message= $_POST['message'];
            $formcontent= "From: $name \n Message: $message";
            $recipient= "konstantin91@gmail.com";
            $subject= "Contact Form";
            $mailheader= "From: $email \r\n";
            if(strlen($name)==0) {
                $nameErr = "Name is required <br>";
            }
            elseif(strlen($email)==0) {
                $emailErr = "Email is required";
            }
            elseif(strlen($message)==0) {
                $messageErr = "Message is required <br>";
            }
            else {

                echo "$name, thank you for submiting message";
            }
        }
    ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
            <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name"><?php echo $nameErr; ?></p>
            <p>Email: <input type="email" name="email"><?php echo $emailErr; ?></p>
            <p>Message:</p> <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea><br />
            <p><?php echo $messageErr; ?></p>
            <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit1">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Also I removed `die()` because else it makes an exit`before showing the error. However you don't need`die()`here because it sends the form only if server runs the last`else` statement, only if all fields are completed.